# How to apply AutoMapping for null values on database?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core

I have appointment and patient table(user credentials like username password hash and salt) and user will send put request to be owner any appointment if patientID=null(hasn't booked yet).I have UpdateAppointmentDto which will come from user in request body and user will be able to change PatientID for itself.

When I send request on Postman gives me AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping error.I guess because patientID is null thats why.

**Controller**

```
  [HttpPut("{id}")]

    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAppointment(int id,UpdateAppointmentDto updateAppointmentDto)
    {
        var availableAppointment = await _repo.GetAppointment(id);

        _mapper.Map(updateAppointmentDto, availableAppointment);

        if (await _repo.SaveAll())
        {
            return NoContent();
        }

        throw new Exception("$1 Updating appointment {id} failed on save");
    }
```

**GetAppointment(id) from Repo**//Will bring the appointment which we want to send request

```
public async Task<Appointment>GetAppointment(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Appointments.Include(p => p.Patient).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);    
    }
```

**AppointmentModel for Entity**

```
public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
        public int HospitalId { get; set; }
        public Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DoctorId { get; set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public int? PatientId { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
```

**UpdateAppointmentDto**

```
public class UpdateAppointmentDto
    {
        public int? PatientId { get; set; }
    }
```

**ConfigureServices(AutoMapping configuration)**

```
 services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AppointmentRepository).Assembly);
```

**AutoMapperProfiles:Profile**

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles :Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<Appointment, AvilableAppointmentDto>()
             .ForMember(dep => dep.DoctorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Doctor.Name))
             .ForMember(dep => dep.DepartmentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Department.Name))
             .ForMember(dep => dep.HospitalName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Hospital.Name));

            CreateMap<Appointment, UpdateAppointmentDto>();

            CreateMap<Department, DepartmentFoundDto>()
             .ForMember(dep => dep.HospitalName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Hospital.Name))
             .ForMember(dep => dep.HospitalLocation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Hospital.Location));

            CreateMap<Doctor, DoctorFoundDto>()
           .ForMember(dep => dep.DepartmentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Department.Name));

            CreateMap<Patient, PatientLoggedinDto>();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that availableAppointment  is not null with debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> gives me AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping error.I guess because patientID is null

I believe it is not because `patientId` is null. I've tested the following 3 use cases :

1. Source (`updateAppointmentDto`) is null
2. Source property `updateAppointmentDto.patientID` is null
3. Target (`availableAppointment`) is null.

But none of them throws a similar error.

Actually the above error information shows that you didn't add a map configuration or the map configuration is missing.

1. Make sure you've added the mapper configuration:

   ```
   public class OrganizationProfile : Profile
   {
       public OrganizationProfile()
       {
           CreateMap<UpdateAppointmentDto, Appointment>();
           // ... others
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you've enabled the mapper service and registered that map configuration by something below:

   ```
   services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
   ```

   (Assuming your `OrganizationProfile` class resides in the same assembly of `Startup` class)

   BTW, I'm using the following AutoMapper package with ASP.NET Core:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
   ```

Comment: I did what you said.But still same error going on.            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AppointmentRepository).Assembly);
This is what I have in startup,I changed what yours though but didnt work

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek Does the mapper configuration class reside in the same assembly of `AppointmentRepository`?

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek  Could you please try `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(OrganizationProfile));`?

Comment: I tried it didn't work like all other mappings after this.I edited my question and added some configurations I have

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek You created a mapping that maps `Appointment` to `DTO` by `CreateMap<Appointment, UpdateAppointmentDto>();`. Actually, it should be `CreateMap<UpdateAppointmentDto, Appointment >();`

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek `CreateMap<A, B>`  means you can map A to B, if you need the ability to map B to A at the same time, you could make it by  ` CreateMap<A, B>().ReverseMap();` See http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html